# MongoDB merging db

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to merge two mongodb databases?
In a way all records and files from DB2 should be merged to DB1.

I have a Java based web application with several APIs to download file content from the MongoDB. So I'm thinking using bash curl download the file, read the records properties then re-upload (merge) to the destination DB1.

This however will have an issue since the same Mongo _id `ObjectID("xxxx")` from DB2 cannot be transfer to DB1. MongoDB will automatically generate and assign ObjectID("xxxx") value based on what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [Mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [Mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/).

the chance for a duplicate document id (assuming its not the same document) is extremely low. 
and in that case mongo will let you know insertion has failed and you could choose to deal with it however you see fit.

You could also use the [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-write-concern) flag with the restore to decide how to deal with it while uploading.